# how to assign groupings based on attributes?

Tags: r, optimization, grouping, subset, permutation

Imagine, I have a list of 51 personas, each of them has a standardized value inherent to their 6 skills.
Now, I am wondering if there is a programmable way to accurately and equally assign those individuals into equal teams, with the skill levels in mind. I wasn't sure which format of the data is more suitable, but intuitively I decided long dataset will make it easier:

```
df <- structure(list(unique_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L), attribute = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Analytics", 
"Communication", "Creativity", "Problem solving", "Programming", 
"Project management"), class = "factor"), skill_level = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -306L))
```

My idea was to somehow focus on running averages in each skill group, but I have no clue where to start.

Perhaps, I am over complicating the problem, and it may be achieved through a specific set of grouping and sorting operations. Frankly, I am not even sure how to search for some existing assignment problems like that, which is slowing me down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like you want to do cluster analysis. Here is one using kmeans clustering and 4 groups (finding the right number of cluster is a longer story, I'm just guessing here):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# kmeans needs wide format
mat <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = unique_id, names_from = attribute, values_from = skill_level)

# for the clustering we remove the id as it would be seen as a variable
clust <- mat %>%
  select(-unique_id) %>% 
  kmeans(4)

# we can attach group membership back to the data
df_new <- mat %>% 
  mutate(group = clust$cluster)

df_new %>% 
  select(unique_id, group)
#> # A tibble: 51 x 2
#>    unique_id group
#>        <int> <int>
#>  1         1     3
#>  2         2     3
#>  3         3     4
#>  4         4     2
#>  5         5     2
#>  6         6     1
#>  7         7     2
#>  8         8     1
#>  9         9     4
#> 10        10     2
#> # ... with 41 more rows

# and also obtain group averages
group_average <- clust %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  rename(Communication = x1,
         Analytics = x2,
         Creativity = x3,
         "Problem solving" = x4,
         Programming = x5,
         "Project management" = x6)
group_average
#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#>   Communication Analytics Creativity `Problem solvin~ Programming
#>           <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1         2.11       1.94      2.22              2.33       1.94 
#> 2         2          1.22      0.944             2.22       0.667
#> 3         0.833      1.33      1.5               1          0.5  
#> 4         2.78       2.67      2.89              3          2.33 
#> # ... with 4 more variables: `Project management` <dbl>, size <int>,
#> #   withinss <dbl>, cluster <fct>
```

Now the groups are pretty homogeneous, meaning people in each group have relatively similar skill values. If your intention is to get groups that are equally strong, you could randomly select people from the different clusters so that each group has the same number of people from cluster 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: thank you for your method, it is definitely a great starting point for me. Is there any way I can force a limit on the number of members in the newly created teams? Is classification the only way to solve an optimization group assignment problem? Also, can weight to each skill be introduced? Thanks.